# How to add table styles back to table after it has been updated using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I create a table dynamically from json data. I then allow the user to update certain elements in the table. Before the update the table looks as follows:

[image]
I inspect the element and it has the following:

[image]

Then after I update the table, the styles added to the input boxes and selects in the table are removed:

[image]

[image]

I would like to know, how would I add back these styles (i.e `ui-select`, `ui-btn-inner` etc) so that the tables dont lose their styling when I recreate the tables. I want to know how to add back the styles to the select, input and the colour of the "Update TextBooks".

Comment: can u make a fiddle for this at http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to shed some more light on the answer so that people understand everything 100%. I was always calling code that basically kept reconstructing the above table, as seen in the pictures above.

In order to keep adding the jQuery Mobile formatting and css to the table everytime one has to call the `.trigger()` method on the table. So for example I would dynamically create an a table based in the users values entered previously. For this solution lets say my table has an id of id = 'updatetable'.

Thus to fix the above problem simply use:

```
$("#updatetable').trigger('create');
```

after you have dynamically created the table.